# Android C2DM stopped working

Tags: android

I was working on one application which is C2Dm based application. Everything was working absolutely fine till yesterday. But now when ever i send notification to devices it shows **Error: InvalidRegisteration** and **status code is 200.**

I got Registeration id and auth also.

I havn't changed a single work in my coding.
Can anybody help me in this case..

Thanks

Comment: same here...I have also developed app and it shows invalid Registration.... :(

Answer (score 0):

The gmail address in the application code you use
for registering with the c2dm server must be same as the one you are
using to push messages from your server.